# My variable is not turning into a string... Why?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, concatenation

I'm doing some practice on what I learned from Codecademy + other sources. I'm trying to run this code(not finished because of this error):

```
word = input("What word do you want analyzed? ")
word = str(word)
print("word: " + word,
      "length of word" + len(word))
```

But every time I try to do that I get this error:

```
"length of word" + len(word))
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

What am I doing wrong?? Should I put a str() method inside of the len() method?

Comment: `len(string) return INT`, cannot be concatenated with `string`

Comment: `len(string)` returns an integer, you need to cast it to a string for this `str(len(word))`

Comment: @SterlingArcher oh yeahh that's right I forgot that it doesn't make it a string. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I put a str() method inside of the len() method?

No, outside of it

```
print("word: " + word,
      "length of word" + str(len(word)))
```